# Loop through entries taking far too long to finish

Tags: entries, php

I am attempting to loop through my "journalEntries" in order to find duplicates. For some reason, it is taking a very long time to finish and return a response to me. Last time I tested it, it took 12 seconds to finish.

```php
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'journalArticles';
$criteria->limit = 10;
$copies = array();

for($a = 0; $a < count($criteria); $a++) {
  for($b = $a + 1; $b < count($criteria); $b++) {
    if($criteria[$a]->title === $criteria[$b]->title) {
      array_push($copies, $criteria[$a]->title);
    }
  }
}

$this->returnJson($copies);
```

I think it is something I am doing incorrectly within the two for loops. As you can see, I limit the amount of articles to only 10, so something seriously funky must be going on. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work and be faster.

```php
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'journalArticles';
$criteria->limit = 10;
$entries = $criteria->find();

$titles = array();
$copies = array();

foreach ($entries as $entry)
{
    $titles[] = $entry->title;
}

foreach (array_count_values($titles) as $val => $count)
{
    if ($count > 1)
    {
        $copies[] = $val;
    }
}

$this->returnJson($copies);
```

Comment: This is legit. I have it working now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Just some side notes as an explanation why your code takes so long and to understand Craft a little bit more
your `count()` function does actually this:

```php
public function count()
{
    // If the query has already been executed, just return a count of the results.
    if (isset($this->_matchedElements))
    {
        return count($this->_matchedElements);
    }

    $total = $this->total();

    if ($this->offset)
    {
        $total -= $this->offset;

        if ($total < 0)
        {
            $total = 0;
        }
    }

    if ($this->limit && $total > $this->limit)
    {
        $total = $this->limit;
    }

    return $total;
}
```

So it checks if there are cached elements and if not the `total` function is executed

```php
public function total($attributes = null)
{
    $this->setAttributes($attributes);

    $this->_includeInTemplateCaches();

    if (!isset($this->_cachedTotal))
    {
        $this->_cachedTotal = craft()->elements->getTotalElements($this);
    }

    return $this->_cachedTotal;
}
```

Which only caches the number but **not** the elements

So what you actually do is executing the query about 100 times (because of your two loops)

Just using `$entries = $criteria->find()` and looping through your entries is a far better idea

Comment: I should have just waited on you to answer. :)

Comment: It's good you answered first because I would have done some nasty workaround since I forgot about the `array_count_values()` function. With your answer he has a solid code, I just wanted to show some things behind the scene (I hope this is the correct reason why it took so long because the longer I look at the code the more I have the feeling I make a fool of myself)

Comment: Testing the code out now ~_~

Comment: Thanks again for diving deep and explaining whats going on behind the scenes. So what your saying is that since I did not use the find method, and set that result to a variable, I am querying the database for the elements 100 times? Holy crapola.

Comment: @RobinSchambach Nope, I think you're right... the first example was basically O(n²) algorithm, so with 10 inputs you get 100 executions.